# WSO2 Identity Server not returning requested claims with OAuth/OpenID

Tags: oauth, wso2, claims-based-identity, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying out OAuth/OpenID with WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0, but I'm having problems with returning the claims I need. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how this should work...

I'm using the default resident identity provider.

The service provider has the claims configured like this:
[image]

This only other configuration for this SP is inbound authentication with OAuth2.

When I get an OAuth token for this service using the openid scope, the JWT received only has the subject field (email address in this case). I was expecting to also receive the requested claims, i.e., roles.

Is this not the way to do it? If not, how can I achieve this? (note: was hoping to keep this to OAuth/OpenID only).

Any help is much appreciated, as I'm quite stumped with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, we have identified certain limitations when trying to retrieve requested claims in an OpenID token.

However, you can try out the below scenario,

1. So basically you need to pick claims that have a mapping between the **"http://wso2.org/oidc/claim"** dialect to **"http://wso2.org/claims"** dialect 
   (I would suggest you try out email, lastname and country for example)
2. Make sure that the claim values are filled in the user profile.
3. Obtain the OpenID token using **Authorization Code** grant or **Implicit grant**

By using the WSO2 Identity Server beta pack[1] you should be able to successfully retrieve the claims as well as a 'sub' claim with the claim that you set as the Subject Claim URI

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.2.0-beta

Comment: Thank you so much, worked wonderfully with the implicit grant AND the password grant. Apologies for the delayed feedback btw, I had no way to test this on the weekend.Thanks again!

Comment: My bad, it doesn't seem to work for password grant after all, the token of the implicit grant was still on cache. Unfortunately, I'm forced to work with password grant. Is it not supported yet, or is there some additional step I'm overlooking?

Comment: I have created a JIRA to track the issue https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4603. We'll fix this soon.

Comment: That'd be wonderful, thanks for the update! I'll follow it up on the JIRA :)

Comment: Still useful as a reminder. I forgot to check if my users have their profile fullfilled, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity. Did you include the `claims` request parameter to request your custom claim? Because *OpenID Connect Core 1.0, [5.5. Requesting Claims using the "claims" Request Parameter](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClaimsParameter)* says as follows:

> Using the `claims` parameter is the only way to request Claims outside the standard set.

I guess you have to use the `claims` request parameter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion! I'm not sure if I'm making this right, but you mean something like this: grant_type=password&...&scope=openid&claims=roles? I followed up your suggestion with some research, and also tried to use scope=openid%20profile, though no difference either. Could it be not supported by wso2is?

Comment: @lv Yes, but the format of the value of the `claims` request parameter is not simple. See the specification for details, or ask WSO2 team.

Comment: Well, I believe I am making a mess of it, either that or it's still not working. I'll test around some more, and then I'll hit up the WSO2 team as suggested. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction though, much appreciated!

Comment: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4603 not yet integrated inside version wso2 5.10 of docker distribution. Standard claims like email, should be claimed using the [scope](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.section.5.4) parameter but at this moment we can get only "sub" attribute. unfortunately, connectors like [mozilla-django-oidc](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-django-oidc) cannot get the email attribute easily to integrate this client with wso2 identity server. seems that a merge can solve this situation.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR this is a bug of the IS5.1.0 product. This will be fixed in WSO2 Identity Server 5.2.0 release. You can test it with the IS5.2.0 beta [1]

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.2.0-beta

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thanks for the link! I installed a fresh version of 5.2beta, but the behaviour is the same as above, i.e., no claims. Any other ideas, or even workarounds? Thanks again.

Comment: The mapped attribute for the http://wso2.org/claims/role in wso2 dialect is "
"role" (you can check that in claim configurations). There is no claim in oidc dialect which has a mapped attribute "role".So, the claim transformation will not work. So, first, you need to add a new claim to oidc dialect with mapped attribute "role", then it will return the claim you want

Comment: That did the final trick, worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4603 not yet integrated inside version wso2 5.10 of docker distribution.

Comment: Tested configuration using wso2 identity server 5.10 and mozilla-django-oidc. you should configure the claims for the service provider to do the request. Generally user and email are required attributes to load. 
Configuration reference can be found here: 
https://github.com/andhdo/mozilla-django-oidc-wso2-is/blob/master/mozilla-django-oidc-wso2-is%20(0026_01_IdentityServer)_1.pdf