# Not receiving claims from WSO2 Identity Server (v5.1.0) when used with Oauth2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server as the identity provider for our websites. The websites are being developed in ASP.net and we are using in-built Owin-Katana framework along with Oauth 2 to authenticate users. I could access SCIM REST Api's to create new users and their claims into WSO2. The claims were added under the dialect "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0". I need to retrieve those claims while authenticating the user via Oauth 2. The service provider setup doesn't allow me to select claims from the dialect "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0".

Is there an way I can retrieve the claims I have added to the user? The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074119/wso2-identity-server-not-returning-requested-claims-with-oauth-openid) here suggest that we install an upgraded version of WSO2. Is that the only solution?

My Owin setup is (using NuGet package Owin.Security.Providers.WSO2):

```
app.UseWSO2Authentication(new WSO2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    BaseUrl = "https://identityserver:9443/",                
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation"),
    ClientId = "xxxxxxxxx",
    ClientSecret = "yyyyyyyyy"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a user's claims via the SCIM API.

Example of a get request :

> curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic `(base64 adminUsername:adminPassword)`" "https://`ishost`:`ismgtport`/wso2/scim/Users?filter=userNameEq`userstoredomain`/`userId`"

```
{
  "schemas": [
    "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0",
    "urn:scim:schemas:extension:wso2:1.0"
  ],
  "totalResults": 1,
  "Resources": [
    {
      "wso2Extension": {
        "nodeId": "2800",
        "employeeNumber": "TEST01"
      },
      "id": "e8a1791f-af81-4d61-ad33-51fd80c4d716",
      "roles": [
        "STORE_MANAGER"
      ],
      "name": {
        "familyName": "Manager",
        "givenName": "Mr"
      },
      "userName": "userstoredomain/userId",
      "phoneNumbers": [
        "0000000000"
      ],
      "externalId": "1_TEST01",
      "meta": {
        "lastModified": "2017-03-27T14:33:05",
        "created": "2017-03-27T14:33:05",
        "location": "https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/e8a1791f-af81-4d61-ad33-51fd80c4d716"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/SCIM+APIs

The above example is retrieved via version 5.0.0

Comment: Yes, I can do and it will be my last resort. But I want to use OAuth2 protocol and get claims as a part of authenticated result.

Answer (score 0):

As point 1 says in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074119/wso2-identity-server-not-returning-requested-claims-with-oauth-openid) you need to pick claims that have a mapping between the "http://wso2.org/oidc/claim" dialect to "http://wso2.org/claims" dialect.

Mapping is checked from Mapped Attribute value of each claim. Say Email claim in http://wso2.org/oidc/claim dialect and Email claim in http://wso2.org/claims dialect has the Mapped attribute as mail, try mapping the mail attribute to the required claim in urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0 dialect. When requesting claims in the service provider, request the claim in http://wso2.org/oidc/claim dialect which has the Mapped Attribute value to your claim.

Hope this would help.